# Stop element from being dragged off screen on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, touchmove

I have an element that can be dragged up/down.  If the user is at the top of the page, the element (*div*) will stop dragging when it gets 50px from the top (same for bottom if user is scrolled all the way to the bottom).

**The Problem:** If the user scrolls down the page just a little then the *div* can be dragged out of view.  I would like for it to stop before it goes out of view from the top and the bottom.  Picture cell phone screen, you can drag a little box on right side of your screen up/down, but can't drag it out of view, even when you scroll up/down the page.

I know I need to figure out whether the page is scrolled then subtract that from the document height, etc, etc...(or something like that).  Or maybe there is a better solution I don't know about.

Here is what I have so far that makes the div *draggable* along the y axis:

```
    this.makeDraggable = function(){
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var winHeight = $(window).height();

        if(eventSupported('touchstart')){
            el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
        }

        function handleMove(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
            var bottom = winHeight - y;

            if(bottom > 50 && y > 50)
            $el.offset({
                top: y
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 this.makeDraggable = function(){
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var winHeight = $(window).height();

        if(eventSupported('touchstart')){
            el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
        }

        function handleMove(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var winScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // scrolled away from top
            var y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
            var top = winScroll + 50;
            var bottom = winScroll + winHeight - 50;

            if(bottom > y && y > top)
            $el.offset({
                top: y
            });
        }
    }
```

$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() is always going to be the bottom of the "window".